# Python list out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I am having issues with indexing items in a list, I am unsure why i am getting the error "list index out of range".

using a basic for loop with Zip I am moving through both list returning a product of both.

Please see my code below:

```
perc = []
for x,y in zip(value[8:],value[:-8]):
    perc.append((value[x]/value[y]))
```

As when I  check the length of both lists `len(value[8:]), len(value[:-8])` both appear to be the same length.

Comment: can you show the contents of `value`

Comment: `perc = [x/y for x,y in zip(value[8:], value[:-8])]`?

Comment: I suspect your issue is that `value` will be a list of integers that your trying to calculate against. However you then put each integer value in `x` and `y` and then you do your calculation by looking up the value list using `x` and `y` as the index which probably doesnt exist. did you maybe just mean to do `perc.append(x/y)`

Comment: @Leporo, you are right.. my brain is not functioning right now. I will go get some coffee

Comment: @ChrisDoyle the content of value is not needed it is a list of integers. using it to populate a Sankey diagram. Yes your second part was correct

Comment: @samc then thats your issue, dont use the integers in `x` and `y` as indexes to look up value just use `x/y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating over the *elements* of the list, but trying to use them as list *indices*.

So if your list is

```
 [10]
```

`value[:8]` is `[10]`, `value[-8:]` is `[10]`.

Then in the loop your `x = 10, y = 10`.

Then you try to do `value[x]/value[y]`, which is `value[10]/value[10]`.

But `10` IS out of range for your list.

Edit: Mixed up the slicing, but the point remains.